# Deletion in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP and MySQL to create a drop box system. The problem I am facing is that I need to delete a folder and delete all the folders and files inside it. It works fine with two folders but when I have 3 folders it does not delete them. Below is the code in PHP. please help me.

```
<?php
session_start(); 
require 'connection.php';
$folderid = $_GET['folderid'];


function rrmdir($dir) {  
if (is_dir($dir)) {
$objects = scandir($dir);
foreach ($objects as $object) {
  if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
    if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") 
       rrmdir($dir."/".$object); 
    else unlink   ($dir."/".$object);
  }
}
reset($objects);
rmdir($dir);
 }
  $delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM file WHERE id='$folderid'");
}




if($folderid != ""){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT file.path FROM ftpdb.file WHERE ftpdb.file.fileID =         $folderid");
$qry = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$dir = $qry['path'];
//Calls a function which deletes all the files and folder in a pathy specified above
rrmdir($dir);
//Delete From database files and folders if the folderID is not null 
$delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM file WHERE fileID='$folderid' OR parentFolder = '$folderid'");
$deleteFiles = mysql_query("DELETE FROM file_files WHERE folder_id = '$folderid'");
$_SESSION['error'] = "Folder has been deleted";
header("location: client.php");
}else{
$_SESSION['error'] = "Error occured please try again";
header("location: client.php");
}
?>
```

This is the database I have managed to delete test folder when I delete home but not testing which is in tests. I think that the sql statement is incorrect
[image: The database is shown in the image below]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you would want to find it out by yourself. So let me just provide you with an appropriate google link: https://www.google.de/search?q=mysql+recursion

If you want to know how to convert an arbitrarily sophisticated select statement into a delete statement:

`DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT file.path FROM ftpdb.file WHERE ftpdb.file.fileID ='$folderid'");
```

Comment: it is deleting the problem is that the thirg folder is getting the id of 81 and the sql stsament only deletes where folder id =72

Answer (score 0):

You only have one value of `$folderid`.  Imagine if `rrmdir` recurses very deep, removing lots of folders.  You cannot catch them all by removing `$folderid` and things with `$folderid` as the parent.  That only goes one level deep!

Your SQL code will need to go inside `rrmdir`, so that you can also remove things from the database recursively.

Then to remove all the folders you will either need to:

- Find the ID of every folder.  (You could pull this from SQL when looping the children, and pass it as a second argument to `rrmdir`.)
- Or, find the record to remove by its pathname, not its ID.

I also note that your last record has two slashes at `//testing`.  This will make it harder to find a match by path!  I would recommend flattening paths like that before they enter the database!

I am also thinking of making my own Dropbox, but I was planning to use something like [unison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unison_%28file_synchronizer%29), driven by a couple of shellscripts.